# CloudBuild fastlane task failing with JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH

Tags: docker, google-cloud-build

I am attempting to run a fastlane build inside `Google Cloud Build` however I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

My first step is to install the Android SDK, which works fine, and then run the fastlane command, however each and every time, no matter what I do in the `name` before the `id:fastlane` I get the same Java error. I've downloaded both the Android and Fastlane images from the [Cloud Builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders) and [Community Cloud Builders](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community) github repo and placed them in our GCP project repository, so each are accessible in the `name` tasks.

```
steps:
  # Android SDK
  - name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/android:29'
    id: android
    args: ["./gradlew", "assembleDebug"]

  # run fastlane
  - name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/fastlane'
    id: fastlane
    args: ['distribute_staging', 'signingPassword:${_PASSWORD}', 'firebaseToken:${_TOKEN}']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that each step are containers. They are loaded one by one, the tasks performed and unloaded. Only the `/workspace` directory is kept from one step to another one.

Therefore, in your first step you load an android builder and you can build Java stuff because Java is installed in the container. Then unloaded

The second step is Fastlane. Look at the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/blob/master/fastlane/Dockerfile), it's a ruby image. No Java inside, thus, your process can't work. You have to build a custom worker

- Either from the fastlane base image and install Java on it
- Or from a Java image (Android?) and install Ruby and fastlane on it.

Comment: Thank you... totally missed that and clears up so much. Follow up question - I've done both: installed rub via `apt-get install ruby ruby-dev` and `gem install java`, and in both instances the next attempt to use those libraries result in errors saying either ruby or java, respectively, have not been added to the path. Is this an additional step I need to take or is this a quirk of using Cloud Builders?

Comment: You can update the path in your dockerfile like this `RUN export PATH=/path/that/you/want:$PATH`